# Database index creation Vs User creating indexes for a table

Tags: mysql, oracle, indexing

I have a mysql database. When I enter the data in a table[T_ID, T_Name, T_AGE] (say around 10k rows.) Will the database implicitly create indexes for this table. If so, then what will happen if I create index my-self using **"Create Index .. ON say T_ID"**. Will both the indexes exists or which one will actually be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `primary key(t_id)` then it will create automaticaly an index and you won't be able to create another one on the same column.

why you don't try these cases?

Comment: Yes, I got message saying "such column list already indexed"(Oracle). Now I got the result. If the table has primary key then you no need else you define your column and give indexes.

Comment: I read that if the indexes are sorted database search uses Binary Search. But if I declare a primary key and primary key column is not sorted then how the seach happens .. pls clear me this one too ..:)

Comment: in general, indexes are other objects than tables. They contains a map of keys and thier phisical address in the table. Keys are sorted in the index, not in the table. if you shoot an `select * from table where id = 20000` the DB engine makes an binary search in the index, finds the key and the phisical address of the row in the table, and then go to the table and gets the row. These are basic concepts about DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on storage engines in MySQL.

In case of `InnoDB` storage engine if you don't specify any `PRIMARY KEY` on `ID` column then internally it will automatically create a `clustered index`. see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html).

In case of `MyISAM` storage engine you can explicitly specify `PRIMARY KEY` on `ID` field.

Secondary indexes are optional in both the cases.

Comment: indeed. The key point here being that there are differences in default primary key indexing behaviour between these two databases.  At the end of the day you should check the table metadata after creation to see if the indexes are as you expect. ( e.g. via the indexes tab in squirrelSQL)